# ODBC Errors in client application connecting to MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sqlncli

Hello the issue started like month ago, when our administrators updated Windows servers to latest updates and our customer start having weird error messages in certain time window from 6am to 8am on client application.
The message is saying:

**ODBC-Error: 08502 TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (t-sql script)**

The script in message is different in every error window and its always a SQL script to database. That scripts is just **SELECT**s of some data in database and its working fine in SSMS. After couple of error windows appears in and its closed by simple click on OK button in error window, the application usually works normal but in several cases it freezes and require a restart of application which causes a customer to be kinda mad because its repeating every day.

The customer application using 32bit ODBC driver SQL Server Native Client 11.0 with version 2011.110.**7462.06** and at database server is SQL Server Native Client with version 2011.110.**5643.03** .Can this difference between versions od ODBC drivers causing the issue ? From 6am to 8am is possible that bigger amount of users are connecting to application and querying the database

Im using SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: I'd be looking at network issues first: has part of the network moved from fibre/cable to Wifi? Are there new IDS boxes on the network that could be interfering with the TDS protocol? Another common issue is green administrators changing Windows Server Power Profiles from High Performance to Balanced which can effectively halve SQL Server performance.

Comment: Thanks for quick response ! Nothing has changed at network side just that Windows were updated. You are right Power options on server was on Balanced. I will try to change it to High Performance and consult the changes with customer tomorow. I will update you with new information.

Comment: I am very sorry for the delay that I could not connect with our customer yesterday, so today I have some news. Nothing has changed about our problem, just what I mentioned was changing the option from balanced to high performance, but it doesn't help at all. Do you have any other suggestions?